# Power BI - How to show next 2 days of selected date?

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI and I am having difficulties. I have some slicers as filters and two chart as below:
[Sample Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ITK.png)

The bottom chart shows data with data according to date selected in the slicers which is straight forward. E.g. The slicer selected 15-Oct-2017, the bottom chart should shows 15-Oct-2017 as well.

The upper chart should shows the next 2 days of the selected chart, i.e. data of 16&17-Oct-2017 should be shown. How do I achieve this in a dynamic way so that when slicer selection change, this chart changes accordingly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by creating 2 measures like that:

```
NextDayValue = CALCULATE(COUNT([columnYouWantToCount]), DATEADD([DateColumn],1,day))
Next2DayValue = CALCULATE(COUNT([columnYouWantToCount]), DATEADD([DateColumn],2,day))
```

and then use these measure in your charts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think the point is your model, can you tell me table and column of the date, and table and column of the counter?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Refer to link below for complete solution

[Solution Here](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-show-next-2-days-of-selected-date/m-p/335396#M150062)